# Расчет суммы динамического диапазона VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Суть проблемы.

В ячейку надо записать формулу, которая суммирует диапазон значений ячеек. Этот диапазон может меняться. Длина задается переменной, да еще и цикл по строкам.

Например, мне надо посчитать сумму 8 ячеек и записать результат в 9ую ячейку. И так для 6 строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кусок кода:

```
numberOfStudent = Range("E6").Value
For n = 1 To numberOfStudent
    Cells(9 + n - 1, 3 + lastValue).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(9 + n - 1, 3), Cells(9 + n - 1, 3 + lastValue - 1)) & ")"
Next n
```

В третьей строчке мне выдает ошибку runtime-error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: Попробуйте написать `Range(Cells(9 + n - 1, 3), Cells(9 + n - 1, 3 + lastValue - 1)).Address`

Comment: @Эдуард, огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение `Range(Cells(9 + n - 1, 3), Cells(9 + n - 1, 3 + lastValue - 1))` возвращает объект типа `Range`, а формула ожидает строку. Чтобы это код работал, в формулу нужно передать адрес строки, это делается с помощью метода `Address` объекта `Range`. В итоге Ваш код должен выглядеть следующим образом

```
numberOfStudent = Range("E6").Value
For n = 1 To numberOfStudent
    Cells(9 + n - 1, 3 + lastValue).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(9 + n - 1, 3), Cells(9 + n - 1, 3 + lastValue - 1)).Address & ")"
Next n
```